# cakephp adding create ?url= in form create

Tags: security, cakephp, components

I am debugging using the security component.  I have a very simple login form on my home page and when I create the form using:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('class'=>'form','url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')));
```

there is NO appending to url, that is when I look at fields in FormHelper $fields, the first element looks like this:

```
[0] => /users/login
```

However, when posting my credentials, the _validationPost in the security component looks like this:

```
[0] => /users/login?url=users%2Flogin
```

The request gets Black-Holed.

If I call login from the User Controller as: /users/login I get:

```
[0] => /users/login?url=users%2Flogin
```

and I don't get black-holed as my form create looks like this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('class'=>'form'));
```

I'm using Max OS X (Mavericks).  I'm not sure if this is a configuration issue.

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Comment: Looks like it could be a `mod_rewrite`/non-pretty URL issue, depends on your version and configuration... that being said, please always mention the exact CakePHP version you are using and tag your question accordingly!

Comment: Sorry, I have tried this in both 2.5.1 and 2.5.2.  I will investigate mod_rewrite and post back if I find anything.

Comment: Well, if you're using 2.x then that's probably not the problem, at least not in the way I was thinking about it, as CakePHP 2.x doesn't use the `url` parameter in the rewrite rules anymore, still worth checking it out though.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer.  It was indeed an issue with how i had set up my mod_rewrite.  More specifically, it was in my .htaccess.  I was using a very old version of .htaccess.  Once I updated, it worked as expected.  Thank you!!!

Comment: You're welcome. So you were probably using the `.htaccess` file of an older 1.x CakePHP version? I'd suggest that you add that as an answer and accept it later on so that the question appears resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this issue was indeed related to mod_rewrite.  I was using an older version of .htaccess (from cakephp version 1.x).  Once I updated the .htaccess in the webfoot folder, my issue was resolved.